# Convergence of sequences $\{u_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $\{v_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\{u_n\}$ and $\{v_n\}$ be two sequences satisfying the conditions

- $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|u_n-v_n|=0$,
- $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|u_n|=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|v_n|=+\infty$.

Prove that
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{u_n}{|u_n|}-\frac{v_n}{|v_n|}\right)=0.
$$

Comment: Are they (purely) real or could they be complex numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $||u| - |v|| \le |u - v|$, and $$ \frac{u}{|u|} - \frac{v}{|v|} = \frac{u}{|u|} - \frac{v}{|u|} + \frac{v}{|u|} - \frac{v}{|v|}$$ so
$$ \left| \frac{u}{|u|} - \frac{v}{|v|}\right| \le \frac{|u - v|}{|u|} + \left| \frac{|v|}{|u|} - 1 \right|$$

The hypotheses could be weakened considerably: it is enough for $|u_n| \to \infty$ with $\frac{|u_n - v_n|}{|u_n|} \to 0$.  Moreover, this could be in any normed linear space.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  What are the possible values of $\frac x{|x|}$?

Comment: That will work for the real case.

Comment: @RobertIsrael:  good point.  I took them as real.